# Spring security config defaultsuccessurl() annotation

Tags: spring, security, authentication, controller, config

[image]

[image]

Hello, I don't know why when I log in, it doesn't redirect in my home page.

Comment: i can't redirect to my homePage which i mention in the function defalutsuccessUrl("/home",true)

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and paste it, formatted as a code (instead a link to an image).

Comment: Thank you to reply me , for example i want once i login i redirect to my page /home...

Comment: Please does somebody may help me ?